# In Amulet, a man named David died in a car accident in the prologue

Tags: amulet

Why were Karen Hayes and her kids Navin and Emily (the heroes) especially devastated by this kind man’s death?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[David (Hayes)](https://amulet.fandom.com/wiki/David_Hayes) is Karen Hayes' husband and father to their two children, Navin Hayes and Emily Hayes. We get confirmation in the first couple of pages what their relationship is, or rather was.

[image]

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amulet_(comics))

> After David Hayes died in a car accident, his widow, Karen, and their children, Emily and Navin, move to a house in the town of Norlen near San Francisco, as Karen hopes a new location will help them reboot their lives.